# Why is my blood group O -ve?

Tags: human-genetics, blood-group

My parents have B +ve blood group in fact my brother also have B +ve blood group, then why my blood group is O -ve ?

Comment: Due to our being diploid, we have 2 genes for deciding blood type. the gene for blood type O is recessive and so is the Rh-. If your blood type is O- and your parents are B+ then your parent's genes are BO+/- for both of them. and you inherited O AND - from both of your parents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Humans are diploid organism. So humans have two copies of every chromosome and gene.

When a person has B blood. We mean that the blood cells of that person expresses  the B antigen.

To produce the B antigen you will need at least one allele for the B antigen. Hence the B antigen phenotype can have a genotype of BB or BO.

Now if two people have the genotype of BO have children, a punnet square will show they they have a 25% of having a child with BB genotype, 50% of having a child with BO genotype and 25% of having a child with OO genotype.

Phenotypically, it means that there is 75% chance of having a child with B blood. And 25% chance of a child with O blood.

A similar system also occurs with rhesus +/- system. A person with +ve blood can have a genotype of ++ or +-. If two people with the genotype of +- have children together, there is a 25% chance that their child will have -- genotype and be rhesus -ve.

The two systems work together. So two people with genotype of BO blood type and +- rhesus antigen having children together, they can have a child with O blood and rhesus negative with a probability of 1/16 (6.25%)